# xframe_options_exempt not working with django (Bitnami)

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, x-frame-options, clickjacking

So I've configured a website that allows me to display data from the waves blockchain onto a django site running on an AWS EC2 instance.

I used bitnami to install a stack image of django onto the server.

The webpage works as shown here www.wavesico.tk/Project/get-ico/jacks-easter-eggs

Django version = 1.11.6

My url correctly points to my view (as the URL above works) urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^$', default_urlconf),
   url(r'^createICO/$', initialForm),
   url(r'^get-ico/([\w-]+)/$', crowdFund),     
]
```

In my views file I have included:

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt
```

and

```
@xframe_options_exempt
def crowdFund(request, company_name):
    c = WavesCompany.objects.get(name=company_name)

    data = tokens.getTokenData(c.holdersKey, c.tokenKey)

    return render(request, 'crowd_fund.html', data)
```

I have also included the middleware in my settings file:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

However, Chrome still reports the error 'Refused to display 'https://www.wavesico.tk/Project/get-ico/jacks-easter-eggs/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

I have tried changing the 'render()' function to 'HttpResponse' but still no luck.

Thanks everyone, 
Jack

Comment: Which Django version are you using? Please show you complete middleware setting. Are you certain that the url is being handled by the view with the decorator?

Comment: Hi Alasdair, 
Thanks for the reply I've edited my question. Im using django 1.11.6.
Im sure the URL works as if you try the url in the question it correctly points to the information. However, when accessing the info through an IFrame you get the 'sameorigin' error
Thanks again

Comment: The code you've posted looks ok. Double check that you've deployed the code above and restarted your server.

Comment: I have done and the error that is returned to Chrome is 'Refused to display 'https://www.wavesico.tk/Project/get-ico/jacks-easter-eggs/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin''. Could this be to do with the fact I've used bitnami to deploy django to the server?

Comment: No, its all django and not bitnami.    You're not getting this issue in local dev?

Comment: [This page](https://community.bitnami.com/t/embed-page-with-iframe-using-ip-address/43130) suggests that the bitnami Apache config may be setting the `X-Frame-Options` header.

Comment: Alasdair - thank you so much thats worked, turns out theres a second headers module at the bottom of bitnamis httpd.conf file that switches all xframe options to SAMEORIGIN regardless of django functionality. Would you like to post this as an answer so I can up-vote you?

Answer (score 0):

As quoted by Alasdair in the comments, if you use a bitnami stack image to initiate your server, bitnami will create two apache documentation folders on top of each other.

As described in this link [https://community.bitnami.com/t/embed-page-with-iframe-using-ip-address/43130](http://bitnami%20apache)

You should be able to find another apache configuration file which sets all x-frame options to SAMEORIGIN, you must change this to your preference as well as in the actual bitnami config files.